# How does a Hololens determine its IP address?

Tags: ip-address, hololens

I have developed some simple applications for the Hololens I have here. This Hololens was set up by someone else. I have no problems connecting to it and deploying my applications.

My main question is **How does the hololens determine its IP address?**

---

I am *not* asking how can I know which IP address the hololens have. Obviously, I already know since it is necessary for deploying.

---

My second concern is that I have seen several Hololens tutorials and many of them use an IP address of the form 192.168.1.x (private network). Mine uses one of the form 10.x.x.x (also private network) 
How come the hololens use private network IPs and yet connect to the internet?

The reason I am asking this is that I need the Hololens to be in the private network of 192.168 to be able to connect to other devices. But apparently, there is no way to change the IP address

Comment: Do you have any reason to think it doesn't just use DHCP like 99% of networked hardware out there?

Comment: "How come the hololens use private network IPs and yet connect to the internet?" — Do you have any reason it doesn't use NAT just like 99% of devices on LANs?

Answer (score 2):

The Hololens does nothing unusual when connecting to a network.  Therefore, all resources online teaching how computers and laptops connect to the internet are applicable to the Hololens.  So, for all intents and  purposes the first answer is answered already by https://superuser.com/questions/575895/how-do-routers-assign-ip-addresses and any introductory networking course online.

The last part (connecting to other devices) depends on the platform you're using.  If using Unity, you may use UNET or Photon, which provide discovery of other Unity games.  Or your programming language will have SNMP libraries to manually scan your local network if you need to write your own.  If working in Hololens, you likely use the MRTK, which has some networking examples which enable Hololens discovery and communication.